# Get the remaining text after subtring

Tags: c#

how can I get the remaining text/values of `ImageString` and return it in a variable? In my current code below i got an error.

Note: `ImageString = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAARCAOEAlgDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQABAAICAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGAwQBAgcICf/EAEkQAQABAwMCAgcCDAMFBgcAAAABAgMEBREhMTIGEgciQVFhcYETkQgUIzNCUnKCobHB0RVikkNjc7LwFhckNKL`

```
var _strings= { response = "True", name = "John", ImageString = "(random text here (1-1000 of characters maybe?))"};
var _split =  _strings.Substring(_strings.IndexOf("ImageString"), _strings.Length);
```

"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Expected Out : I want to get all the text from the "ImageString"

Comment: Can you also share what output do you want, based on the give input ?

Comment: Mystical `qweqwe` came and ruined all your day.. `_strings.Substring(_strings.IndexOf("ImageString"), _strings.Length);`

Comment: your `_strings` looks like a `JSON` string. It would be better to deserialize to an `Object` and get a value from there.

Comment: How is this a string? var _strings= { response = "True", name = "John", ImageString = "(random text here (1-1000 of characters maybe?))"};
 this looks like an anonymous object. Also doing subsrting you have to be 100% sure that IndexOf("ImageString") will be zero or higher because if it don't exist it will return -1 and you can't start subscring from minus one and _string.length represents the length of text but the index for the last character is _string.length-1

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can use JSON serializer:

```
public class Data
{
    public string ImageString { get; set; }
}

var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Deserialize<Data>(_strings);

var myImageString = data.ImageString;
```

Comment: "Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: =. Path '', line 1, position 14."

Comment: @FaceLessNoOne, you can add the code you tried and error message to the answer.

Comment: I added the output of my String. and the error that I encounter after I test the same code as you.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, and you insist on `string` manipulations (not Json parsing)

```
string _strings = 
  "{ response = \"True\", name = \"John\", ImageString = \"bla-bla-bla\" };";
string toFind = "ImageString";

int p = _strings.IndexOf(toFind);

// bla-bla-bla
string remain = p < 0
  ? ""  //TODO: Not found at all (shall we return an empty or entire string?)
  : _strings
      .Substring(p + toFind.Length)
      .TrimStart(' ', '=') // to be on the safe side: what if data starts from =
      .TrimStart('"', ' ')
      .TrimEnd('}', ';', ' ')
      .TrimEnd('"', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _strings= { response = "True", name = "John", ImageString = "(random text here (1-1000 of characters maybe?))"};
```

The above looks like an anonymous object but i am assumming you mean the structure of your text by it.

```
var imageStringIndex= _strings.IndexOf("ImageString");
    var _split =  _strings.Substring(imageStringIndex<0?0:imageStringIndex, _strings.Length - 1);
```

or

```
  var _split =  _strings.Split("ImageString".ToCharArray()).Last();
```

both you work for your case

Answer (score 0):

First problem I'm seeing is that

```
var _strings= { response = "True", name = "John", ImageString = "(random text here (1-1000 of characters maybe?))"};
```

Is not a string, rather an attempt at an anonymous object?

If it is, you can declare the object using:

```
var _strings = new { response = "True", name = "John", ImageString = "(random text here (1-1000 of characters maybe?))" };
```

Then access any property in the object using standard c# syntax:

```
var imageString = _strings.ImageString;
```

The answer to your question depends very much on where the information is coming from as you can declare it and manipulate it in a thousand different ways if you have control over it.